# Need a graph javascript third party plugin

Tags: javascript, graph

I've been searching for a JavaScript graph library that allows me to create a graph similar to a clock where the hand moves over however many seconds I specify it and allows me to add as many titles instead of numbers to it.
Does anyone know of a JS library like this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a radar/spider chart, if I understand correctly. Now you have the right keyword to search, you should be able to find many useful resources.

I have personally tried this implementation before, good if you are familiar with d3.js already: https://github.com/alangrafu/radar-chart-d3

And of course there are other ones such as [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), [anychart](http://www.anychart.com/), etc.